# can't install gnuradio blocks on windows

Tags: git, cmake, command-prompt, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

Some background - I have been trying to capture a signal from an antenna but only write the data stream to a file sink every say 1 second over the course of a 5 second period. So 1 second write to file, 4 seconds off (as in the data is not being recorded to the file sink), then 1 second write to file and repeat until I decide to stop the flowdiagram.

The blocks I am trying to install (I am using windows10) can be found here https://github.com/ghostop14/gr-filerepeater.

The step it tells us to follow to build the blocks upon extraction are as such:
mkdir build

cd build

cmake ..

make

make install

ldconfig

My command prompt says "'cmake'  is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". I decided to install cmake from the website (https://cmake.org/download/) but still get the same problem.

From what I have read, this process seems to be the standard way of getting a block from git to your version of GNURadio and others have commented on how simple it is so I must be fundamentally not doing the right thing. For clarity could someone explain what 'cmake' and 'make' for that matter actually do in the command prompt? Am I totally off track when trying to install the blocks from git? What else do i need to do to get the block onto my GNURadio? What am I not doing?

Comment: What **exact steps** you performed when install CMake from the website?

Comment: I downloaded the cmake-3.19.0-win64-x64.msi and then installed it to my program files directory on my C drive

Comment: So you probably need to add directory with `cmake` executable into the `PATH` variable. Note also, that steps `make`, `make install` are NOT applicable for Windows: neither it has no `make` utility. Actually, you just need to follow common way for building CMake project on Windows. Some description of that process you may found here: https://cmake.org/runningcmake/.

Comment: By default CMake probably selects VS 2019 as generator on windows. Depending on the build system you want to use you may want to specify the generator to use via -G option when setting up the project. Btw: You may want to go with the more platform agnostic way of building the program and use `cmake --build .` and `cmake --install .` instead of `make all` and `make install` respectively.